# Error when trying to build Opa application

Tags: compiler-errors, opa

I'm just trying to build the basic hello_chat application from the Opa docs.
If I try building from the command line using:

```
opa ..filepath\hello_chat.opa
```

I get an error saying

```
Warning inclusions.directory_does_not_exist
Error reading directory: C:\resources
Error encountered: No such file or directory.
Warning inclusions.directory_empty
Directory C:\resources is empty.
Error
An internal error has occurred during the pass ServerJavascriptCompilation
Uncaught Exception:
  Sys_error("hello_chat_depends/load.js: No such file or directory")
Backtrace:
```

If I try to build from Sublime text 2 (using the Opa-one build tool) it puts a file called opa_build and two folders '_build' and 'opa_build_depends'. If I try to run the opa_build file it says that I am using the wrong version of Windows 32 not 64 bit as I used the installer. But I am using a 64 bit version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is a limitation in the last version. For the moment try to compile directly inside your source directory:

```
opa hello_chat.opa
```